# how to populate an array of type string[] using data table in C#

Tags: string

I'm having an issue populating
 string double array using data table.
Please help.

string[][] export = function();

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? What data is in the DataTable? What data are you wanting to put into the array?

Comment: Implementing `function` would be a good first step.  Though calling it "function" is probably a bad idea.

Comment: Here is the complete code:

Comment: string[][] myArray = new string[dt.Rows.Count][dt.Columns.Count](); // Declare the new 2d array

for(i=0; i < dt.Rows.Count-1; i++) // Iterate through the rows
{
 for(j=0; j < dt.Columns.Count-1; j++) // Iterate through the columns
 {
  myArray[i][j] = dt.Rows[i][j]; // Populate the array with the cell data.
 }
}
return myArray

Comment: sorry Here is the code:

Comment: string[][] export = context.GL301000Export
(



new Command[] 
{ 



new Value 
{ 
Value = 


"GL", LinkedCommand = GL301000.BatchSummary.Module
}, 
GL301000.BatchSummary.ServiceCommands.EveryBatchNumber, 



new Field 
{
ObjectName = GL301000.BatchSummary.BatchNumber.ObjectName, 
FieldName = 

},
GL301000.BatchSummary.BatchNumber, 
GL301000.BatchSummary.ControlTotal,
GL301000.TransactionDetails.Account, 
GL301000.TransactionDetails.Subaccount,
GL301000.TransactionDetails.RefNumber,
GL301000.TransactionDetails.CreditAmount,

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to do something like this: 
(dt is your DataTable)

```
string[][] myArray = new string[dt.Rows.Count][dt.Columns.Count](); // Declare the new 2d array

for(i=0; i < dt.Rows.Count-1; i++) // Iterate through the rows
{
 for(j=0; j < dt.Columns.Count-1; j++) // Iterate through the columns
 {
  myArray[i][j] = dt.Rows[i][j]; // Populate the array with the cell data.
 }
}
return myArray
```